# Cloudflare WAF Rule not working properly to block access to pages from specific countries

Tags: wordpress, security, cloudflare, firewall

I have setup cloudflare to block access to WordPress back-end with following WAF rule. It somehow lets me access back-end from other countries other than countries other than Germany and UK.

It was working in past for other site however today i tried configure this for different domain and its not working..

[image]

I want users to access back end of website only from Germany and United Kingdom

[image]

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Blocking too much?  Blocking too little?  Error message?

Comment: It should let me access to backend of Wordpress only from two countries Germany and United Kingdom. When i test i can access website backend pages from all countries https://www.example.com/wp-admin/

Comment: Is there more to the rule you shared in your screenshot?  I don't see anything that says it should be blocked, just what the request matches.

Comment: So only these 3 condition for this rule (http.host eq "example.com" and http.request.uri.path contains "/wp-admin/" and not ip.geoip.country in {"DE" "GB"})

Comment: Where is the configuration to say this should be blocked as opposed to allowed?

Comment: I updated main question where action is set to BLOCK

Comment: The rule is correctly set. I would simplify it by deleting the first part (hostname) as you can do it with just the URI-Path and Country. The ORDER of rules is important, perhaps there's another rule that is allowing access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to make it work after i only added URI path contains and Country..

Comment: Please accept this answer so users know this question has been answered.